# Discord.JS | Music Bot "Error: Video Unavailable"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, ytdl

I'll list the command logic itself and all installed dependencies below. Basically, whenever I run the command in Discord with any youtube link I've given it so far, the bot joins and everything runs correctly but then shortly after, the bot errors out in VSC with the error "Video Unavailable". I've looked through all kinds of forums and watched a lot of videos and I can't find any solution at all.

**Play Command Logic:**

```js
if (musicArgs.startsWith('play')) {

                let musicPlayPrefix = 'play';

                let musicPlayArgs = musicArgs.slice(musicPlayPrefix.length).trim();

                if (message.member.voice.channel) {

                    const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();

                    const dispatcher = connection.play(await ytdl(musicPlayArgs), { type: 'opus'})

                    dispatcher.on('error', console.error);

                    dispatcher.on('start', () => {

                        message.channel.send(`**Now Playing:** *${musicPlayArgs}`);
                    });

                    dispatcher.on('finish', () => {

                        message.channel.send(`**Music Finished!**`);
                    });
                }

                else {

                    message.channel.send(`You're not in a voice channel! Retry the command inside of one.`);
                }
            }
```

**Dependencies in Package.json:**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/opus": "github:discordjs/opus",
    "discord.js": "^12.3.1",
    "ffmpeg-static": "^4.2.7",
    "hypixel-api-reborn": "^2.2.4",
    "libsodium-wrappers": "^0.7.8",
    "ytdl-core-discord": "git+https://github.com/amishshah/ytdl-core-discord.git"
  }
```